# wpf in-page dialog

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

When I worked on web pages I used these a lot.  While building a page out for WPF project the other day I ended up building a page that looked like it had an in-page dialog on it but it was the only thing on the page.

My question here is. Has any one created such component that allows for easy creation of these kinds of dialogs.

Comment: I've developed my own in a few places now as well and it seems that there should be some resources around for doing this in a more consistent manner. I'll report back if I find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace xxx.Wpf
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for InPageDialog.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class InPageDialog : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public InPageDialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void Show(IDialog ucContent)
        {                        
        }

        void ucContent_OnClose(object obj)
        {

        }
        protected virtual void Changed(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentBackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ContentBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(InPageDialog), new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.White));
        public Brush ContentBackground 
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(ContentBackgroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ContentBackgroundProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentBorderBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ContentBorderBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(InPageDialog), new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.White));
        public Brush ContentBorderBrush 
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(ContentBorderBrushProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ContentBorderBrushProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentActiveBackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ContentActiveBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(InPageDialog), new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.White));
        public Brush ContentActiveBackground 
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(ContentActiveBackgroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ContentActiveBackgroundProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentBorderThicknessProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ContentBorderThickness", typeof(Thickness), typeof(InPageDialog));
        public Thickness ContentBorderThickness 
        {
            get { return (Thickness)GetValue(ContentBorderThicknessProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ContentBorderThicknessProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentBlurRadiusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ContentBlurRadius", typeof(double), typeof(InPageDialog));
        public double ContentBlurRadius 
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ContentBlurRadiusProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ContentBlurRadiusProperty, value); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    public interface IDialog
    {
        event Action<object> OnClose;
    }
}

    <UserControl x:Class="xxx.Wpf.InPageDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:me="clr-namespace:xxx.Wpf"
    Visibility="Collapsed" DataContext="{Binding}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="60"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type me:InPageDialog}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}">
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                       Opacity="0.765" 
                       Fill="{TemplateBinding ContentBackground}" />

            <Border VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    CornerRadius="5" 
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding ContentBorderBrush}" 
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding ContentBorderThickness}" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding ContentActiveBackground}" >
                <ContentPresenter Margin="0" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </Border>

        </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

Is a start to the project and works for what we do at my work.